# Update UI from portable library

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm looking for a way to update a bind value from a portable library. This is the structure of my application :

MySolution :

- `MyUiClass` extended from `SecondClass` : in the .xaml I have : `{Binding IsBusy}`
- `PortableLibrary`
- --> `SecondClass` extended from `FirstClass`
- --> `Firstclass` which contains the definition for `IsBusy` variable.

I want to call `NotifyPropertyChanged("IsBusy");` from the `FirstClass` but I get an exception because i don't know how to access to the main thread from the portable library.

Comment: What is the exception? In WPF you can raise PropertyChanged events from any thread, the binding system takes care of marshaling the notification to the appropriate thread

Comment: This is the exception I get :
`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8001010E): The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.PropertyChangedEventArgsMarshaler.ConvertToNative(PropertyChangedEventArgs managedArgs)`

Comment: Ah, so it's WinRT, not WPF; the tags confused me. Well, you need a way to access the Dispatcher somehow; the way I'd do it is to create an interface (e.g. IDispatcherService) to abstract the Dispatcher, and inject it into your ViewModel to give it access to the Dispatcher

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, I'll try it. Sorry for the tag, it's not me who added this one.